# Taylor McLaughlin Series to estimate the distance of two points

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphic, taylor-series

Distance from point to point: dist = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
But sqrt is too slow and I can't accept that. I found a method called Taylor McLaughlin Series to estimate the distance of two points on the book. But I can't comprehend the following code. Thanks for anyone who helps me.

```
#define MIN(a, b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
int FastDistance2D(int x, int y)
{
    // This function computes the distance from 0,0 to x,y with 3.5% error
    // First compute the absolute value of x, y
    x = abs(x);
    y = abs(y);

    // Compute the minimum of x, y
    int mn = MIN(x, y);

    // Return the distance
    return x + y - (mn >> 1) - (mn >> 2) + (mn >> 4);
}
```

I have consulted related data about McLaughlin Series, but I still can't comprehend how the return value use McLaughlin Series to estimate the value. Thanks for everyone~

Comment: I don't understand why your input and the method's input consists of two integers, because if you want to evaluate the distance of two points in 2D you need 4 integers, (x,y) for each point.

Comment: The comment does say from (,0,0) to (x,y). @MapleWan when you say "on the book" which book?

Comment: `dx` conventionally stands for `delta x`, the difference between 2 `x` values.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, you are right, but sometimes, I require the distance value to do some other mathematics computing.

Comment: @doctorlove A book about game programming, which called <Tricks of the windows programming>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is almost duplicate of another one:
[Very fast 3D distance check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693514/very-fast-3d-distance-check)

And there was link to great article:
http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/sqroot.html

In the article you can find different aproaches for approximation of root. For example maybe this one is suitable for you:

```
int isqrt (long r) {
    float tempf, x, y, rr;
    int is;

    rr = (long) r;
    y = rr*0.5;
    *(unsigned long *) &tempf = (0xbe6f0000 - *(unsigned long *) &rr) >> 1;
    x = tempf;
    x = (1.5*x) - (x*x)*(x*y);
    if (r > 101123) x = (1.5*x) - (x*x)*(x*y);
    is = (int) (x*rr + 0.5);
    return is + ((signed int) (r - is*is)) >> 31;
}
```

If you can calculate root operation fast, then you can calculate distance in regular way:

```
return isqrt(a*a+b*b)
```

And one more link:
http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml

```
u32 approx_distance( s32 dx, s32 dy )
{
   u32 min, max;

   if ( dx < 0 ) dx = -dx;
   if ( dy < 0 ) dy = -dy;

   if ( dx < dy )
   {
      min = dx;
      max = dy;
   } else {
      min = dy;
      max = dx;
   }

   // coefficients equivalent to ( 123/128 * max ) and ( 51/128 * min )
   return ((( max << 8 ) + ( max << 3 ) - ( max << 4 ) - ( max << 1 ) +
            ( min << 7 ) - ( min << 5 ) + ( min << 3 ) - ( min << 1 )) >> 8 );
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the **i** nverse square root ? Besides, on modern CPU's that's not a good idea.

Comment: Awesome, the code is far more complicated than I thought, thanks very much. I'll research the code and read the articles you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are right `sqrt` is quite a slow function. But do you really need to compute the distance?

In a lot of cases you can use the distance² instead.
E.g.

1. If you want to find out what distance is shorter, you can compare the squares of the distance as well as the real distances.
2. If you want to check if a `100 > distance` you can as well check `10000 > distanceSquared`

Using the ditance squared in your program instead of the distance you can often avoid calculating the `sqrt`.

It depends on your application if this is an option for you, but it is always worth to be considered.

Comment: ² : squared (I really can't stand missing footnotes ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that's a good idea when I have no complex computing.